# Remove mono bluetooth profile or set stereo as default

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove mono bluetooth profile or set stereo as default.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/738/remove-mono-bluetooth-profile-or-set-stereo-as-default)

Whenever I turn on my Nokia bluetooth headphones they automatically connect to my Macbook. The problem is they always connect to the Mono (and not the Stereo) profile.  So I have to disconnect and reconnect with the stereo profile.  Is there anyway to either delete the mono profile or set the stereo profile as the default?

Mac OS X 10.6
Nokia BH-905